# How to hide context and the `IO` monad into another monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

I am trying to implement a small desktop application, using `HDBC` and `Haskell.GI`. I build my windows and dialogs using glade, and load them with `GtkBuilder`. After implementing a couple of scenarios, I end up using the same pattern throughout, composing "actions" in `do` blocks that have a signature of:

```
Connection -> Builder -> a -> IO b
```

These "actions" compose in the context of the `IO` monad, the main problem being that I have to pass my `Connection` and `Builder` all around. Another problem I foresee is that if I ever want to add another external dependency to my application, (access to an image scanner, for instance) I will have to change the signature of all my "actions", and more importantly, their arity.

What I could do: I could define a type synonym:

```
type Action a b = Connection -> Builder -> a -> IO b
```

I could also create a named tuple to eliminate the arity problem:

```
data Context =
    Context {
        conn :: Connection,
        builder :: Builder}
```

But still, that does not solve the fact that, every time I want to access the database, I will have to call `(conn ctx)` or use a `let` binding in every action.

What I feel would be ideal would be to make my own monad, in which I could compose my actions and I would not speak explicitly about my `Connection` or `Builder` values.

How would I go defining a monad like this, knowing that `IO` is already a monad?

As an aside, has it anything to do with the `State` monad?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look at the Reader monad. (It's indeed similar to the State monad, but the state is read only.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond: OK. What you seem to mean is : if I define the `Context` type as in the question, and define `type Action = ReaderT Context IO`, I can do `(reader conn)`, `(reader builder)` and `liftIO $ do ...` ?

Comment: Not quite - `(ReaderT Context IO) b`, modulo `newtype` wrapping, is equivalent to `Context -> IO b` - so it doesn't include your `a` argument. You could of course rearrange the order of the arguments and use a function `a -> ReaderT Context IO b`

Comment: So `(new)type Action a b = a -> ReaderT Context IO b`would be a proper monadically composable function type. (the monad being `ReaderT Context IO`) I think I get it now.

Comment: Using you own monad you can define your own helpers like `getConnection :: Action a Connection`. You probably want to define a `MonadIO (Action a)` instance as well, so that you can run things like `liftIO (putStrLn "hello")` in your custom monad.

Comment: There is a lot of good discussion here. Could the results be edited into the answer? That would improve it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> [..] the main problem being that I have to pass my `Connection` and `Builder` all around.

So these are part of an "environment" that You read from (repeatedly).  That's what the `Reader` monad is for.  The package `mtl` contains the monad transformer [`ReaderT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#t:ReaderT) which adds reader functionality to a base monad, in Your case `IO`.

### Demo:

Assuming a simple action, like ..

```
no_action :: Connection -> Builder -> Int -> IO Int
no_action _ _ i = return (i + 1)
```

You can put this into a new Monad which is like `IO` but with access to both connection and builder by defining a `Context` and applying the monad transformer:

```
data Context = Context { connection :: Connection
                       , builder :: Builder }
type CBIO b = ReaderT Context IO b
```

Lifting Your actions into this new (combined) monad deserves a function on its own:

```
liftCBIO :: (Connection -> Builder -> a -> IO b) -> (a -> CBIO b)
liftCBIO f v = do
    context <- ask
    liftIO (f (connection context) (builder context) v)
```

Then You can either always write `(liftCBIO no_action) num` or ...

```
cbio_no_action = liftCBIO no_action
```

... and `cbio_no_action num`.

To actually run Your new monad You'd use `runReaderT` .. but this also deserves a better name:

```
runWithInIO = flip runReaderT
```

You could also change this to incorporate building the `Context`, if You like.

Using the above then looks like that:

```
main = do
    i <- runWithInIO (Context Connection Builder) $ do
        a <- cbio_no_action 20
        liftIO $ putStrLn "Halfway through!"
        b <- cbio_no_action 30
        return (a + b)
    putStrLn $ show i
```

[(Full demo on ideone)](https://ideone.com/lQp86T)